# Where would I install an issued SSL certificate to access a suppliers API?

Tags: c#, windows, ssl

I have a project where I need to access a particular payment gateway API. I have done this several times to other suppliers, but these guys have sent me a load of security bits which I have no idea on how to use. (I asked this supplier, but they have no instructions to do this).

I am using Windows, and I'm developing in C#.

They have sent me five files which I am supposed to use to access their API:

- ca.crt
- customer.crt
- customer.key
- customer.p12
- customer.pem

The crt files I have installed, but not sure if I put them in the right place as I get a "400 Bad Request - No required SSL certificate was sent" error.

The other files I am at a loss with. I cannot find what I am supposed to do with them. From what little I have gathered, I think they are an alternative for the crt files?

So, my question: What am I to do with these files? Am I right installing them? If so, where should I install them? Should I send them by code in my application?

I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but I am completely lost on this... I thought that SSL certs were source application side only...

Thanks

Comment: *"I asked this supplier, but they have no instructions to do this"*, sounds like an awesome supplier...

Comment: Not overly impressed so far... He did give me some code samples instead in C++, Perl and PHP. None of which had any mention of any kind of security certificates...